# Branch out a micro-app from an app to improve load times

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have an existing Meteor app that let's users create and manage widgets that they can later embed elsewhere. Essentially, once they have a widget, they can generate an iframe but, as we all know with Meteor, things can get very slow there. So as of right now, that embed takes ~10 seconds to load which isn't great. Most of it probably has to do with the fact that Meteor loads ALL of the app on a route that really doesn't need most of it.

I'd like to branch out the embed functionality to a different app that would communicate with the main DB and load up the widget FAST.

Looking for guidance in terms of how to set it up. There are some outdated boilerplates out there but I'd like to learn more as for the best approach I can take.

Current app:

```
METEOR@1.4.2.3
"react": "^15.3.0",
"react-router": "^2.6.1",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called code splitting. Currently there are no official support for that from Meteor, but the community has proposed some solutions. The newest proposal I know is this https://forums.meteor.com/t/experimental-code-splitting/31938, give it a shot if you really need code splitting, but you should be very careful it is just experimental anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the note! I am a little sceptical since it's an experimental way to implement and will require to remove two core Meteor packages. For now I will just branch out the app into it's own micro-app and see what results it gives me. Still open to more suggestions though :)